# Использование слов "имеется" и "является"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Был у меня один руководитель, который прямо запрещал использование слов "имеется" и "является". Приводились аргументы, что первое, якобы, отсылает к сексу, а второе употребляется исключительно в религиозном контексте. Я заметил, что с тех пор у меня прямо-таки комплекс по поводу их употребления на почве уважения к авторитету этого, надо сказать, хорошего человека.

Так можно ли использовать слова "имеется" и "является" в речи, не опасаясь возможности быть понятым неправильно?

Больше всего меня интересует, грамотно ли использовать эти слова в интерфейсных сообщениях?
Например, подпись к товару "имеется на складе" или чекбокс "являюсь торговым агентом компании".

Comment: Когда обсуждалась  тема, то речь шла о стиле, а не о грамотности, причем о стиле текстов в общем плане.. Если рассматривать использование этих слов в коротких записях делового характера, то в этом случае они вполне грамотны, уместны и общеприняты. Варианты замены: есть на складе, торговый агент компании. Мы же обсуждали причину того, почему ваш руководитель не любил эти слова.  Его аргументы - это ироническое отношение к  словам-штампам, и он хотел, чтобы вы услышали их  значение в других ситуациях.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Прочитав все обсуждения, я наконец-то сформировал полное представление об употреблении этих слов в любых ситуациях и о причинах нелюбви к ним в деловой этике. "Пиши-сокращай" обязательно приобрету.

Answer (score 2):

Подобное отношение к самым невинным словам широко распространено в нашей культуре. Это страх перед эсхрофемизмами, которому в той или иной степени подвержены даже многие приличные люди. И хотя несложно понимать весь идиотизм подобного отношения к словам русского языка, но бороться в одиночку с этим явлением не так просто. Приведу цитату из Википедии:

> Г. Гусейнов «Заметки к антропологии русского Интернета: особенности
>   языка и литературы сетевых людей»
>
> Одно из специфических свойств современных носителей русского языка,
>   людей, говорящих по-русски, это склонность к эсхрофемизмам или
>   суеверный страх перед эсхрофемизмами. Сигнал, заставляющий за невинным
>   словом слышать грубое, ругательное, матерное слово. Почему больше не
>   говорят «я кончил школу»? Нет, «окончил школу», «закончил школу», да
>   потому что этот глагол имеет, оказывается, непристойный подтекст, и
>   вот как бы чего не подумали. Вот это и есть проявление эсхрофемизма.
>   Боятся сказать «последний» или «крайний». Эсхрофемизм — это изнанка
>   эвфемизма. Сначала вместо запретного слова появится «блин», а потом
>   придется запрещать глагол «блеять».

Comment: Но правильно именно "окончил школу". И всегда было правильно. Ещё до всяких подтекстов. Хотя во времена Чехова говорили "в университете кончил", но это безнадежно устарело.

Comment: @Niemand Возьмите толковый словарь Кузнецова и посмотрите в нём слово "кончить". А выдумки о том, что так неправильно, распространились как раз по указанной причине. Прошу Вас не продолжать (а лучше и не вступать) в подобные споры с одними лишь придуманными аргументами. (PS. Но очевидно, что "окончил школу" **тоже** правильно.)

Comment: Бывает, что и словари оказываются не на высоте. Впрочем, с пометой "разг" школу можно и кончить. Но ведь там пометы нет? Словарь Кузнецова вообще последний, на который можно ссылаться (по авторитетности), хотя он самый доступный. )

Comment: @Niemand Интересно, почему это Грамота.ру предлагает нам "последний по авторитетности" словарь.  И на чем основано такое мнение, кроме "я так думаю"?

Comment: @Niemand *Словарь Кузнецова вообще последний, на который можно ссылаться (по авторитетности)* — я понимаю, что с высоты Вашего уровня знания языка словарь Ожегова занимает предпоследнее место, словарь Ушакова — третье с конца, словарь Ефремовой — четвёртое... А какой источник для Вас на первом месте? Неужели одно только Ваше самомнение заслуживает внимания? Вы ни разу не посмотрели ни в один из словарей (хотя бы одно только слово **кончить**)? Если у Вас нет  ни единого аргумента, я не вижу смысла спорить — это всё равно, что ругаться с теми, кто пишет на заборах.

Comment: @Jasmin, не "я так думаю". Поинтересуйтесь мнением филологов, зайдите хотя бы на форумы на той же Грамоте.

Answer (score 1):

Хотя нельзя исключать суеверного  страха людей перед словами, но, мне думается, **здесь совсем другая ситуация.**

К примеру, редактор современного журнала запрещает своим сотрудникам употреблять (и обязательно вычеркивает) **слово "является",** но совсем не по религиозным мотивам.

В информстиле оно относится **к  стоп-словам. Так называют слова мусорные, ненужные**, так как они легко удаляются из текста без потери его смысла, и даже наоборот, содержание становится ясным, легче читается и воспринимается.

Пример из книги "Пиши, сокращай. Как создавать сильный текст" Максима Ильяхова:

На сегодняшний день одной из самых  актуальных проблем россиян **является** безработица. –  Проблема россиян – безработица.

И вот руководитель **воспитывает в студентах (или работниках) комплекс неприятия таких слов весьма оригинальным, но эффективным способом**. Он заставляет  "услышать" их  ненужность через те ситуации, где эти слова имеют конкретный смысл (религиозный или сексуальный).

Разумеется, в словах ***имеется*** и ***является*** **никто не будет искать особый подтекст**, но они  стоят первыми в списке "стоп-слова" информационного стиля речи.

Comment: "Ненужные" слова? Не надо волноваться, язык сам отсеет ненужные слова. Не отсеял? – значит, они "нужные". Все же очень просто. Забавно, что устроили целый консилиум по поводу решения одного самодура. Мало ли самодуров – каждый раз устраивать дебаты? Смешно.

Comment: Не смешно. Информационный стиль сейчас очень востребован, и это неудивительно. Привлечь современного читателя можно только краткими, яркими, содержательными текстами. А имеется и является - это язык устаревших штампов, от которых надо избавляться любыми способами. В данном случае, как видите, прием оказался весьма действенным.

Comment: >> "А имеется и является - это язык устаревших штампов, от которых надо избавляться любыми способами". Вот откуда вы такую ерунду берете? Вас же тут читают и не дай бог возьмут на вооружение. Потому что многие задающие сюда вопросы считают нас авторитетами. Можете привести авторитетные мнения, подтверждающие вашу непримиримую точку зрения? (Так и хочется сказать: "кочку зрения", потому что ну нельзя же так).

Comment: Вы действительно в рекламе написали бы: "На складе много этих изделий"? Тогда вы путаете разговорный стиль с официальным. Увидев такое, многие пройдут мимо, не купят. И знакомым не посоветуют.

Comment: Избегайте оценочных мнений, особенно выраженных в неуважительной для собеседника форме (путать, говорить ерунду), в противном случае ваша риторика может заинтересовать модераторов.. А говорю я то, что знаю, потому что общаюсь с редакторами журналов и знакома с  их требованиями. Для меня их мнение авторитетное, потому что оно оплачиваемое, других доказательств мне не надо.

Comment: Что касается инфостиля, то он вызывает споры, как любое новое явление, но в любом случае каждый может найти в этом методе важное и ценное для себя. Вот недавно слышала, как в магазине искали книгу "Пиши, сокращай. Как создавать сильный текст" Максима Ильяхова, значит, интересуются люди. http://lisel85.ru/copywhiting/seo-copywriting/stop_slova_glavred

Comment: А приведёте пример современной печатной рекламы в этом самом "инфостиле"? Или "инфостиля" в тех самых журналах? И мало ли чем люди интересуются... Это что, аргумент?

Comment: Кстати, если "вызывает споры", то так и надо говорить. А вы как говорите? "Избавляться любыми способами". Ну, очередное модное течение. Через пару лет пройдет.